Custom Dropdown input automatic search behavior in Woocommerce Wordpress
I have 2 custom made dropdowns in Woocommerce, that act as filters for products, one including all brands in the site, the second all level 2 categories. They have an automatic tigger search function so that when the user selects one, it automatically redirects them to the products page matching that criteria, a brand or category. The issue im having is that when a brand is selected in the brands input it displays the correct products for that brand, but when the user tries to refine the search with the categories input nothing happens. On the other hand, if the user chooses the category first and later the brand it does work once, but from there only the brand can be changed to show different results, the category stays stuck in whatever was first chosen. I'm using the Perfect Brands Plugin for Woocommerce on WordPress.
Here's my custom php:
//DROPDOWN SELECT

add_action('wp_ajax_get_products_by_category', 'get_products_by_category_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_products_by_category', 'get_products_by_category_callback');

function get_products_by_category_callback() {
    check_ajax_referer('woo-predictive-search-nonce', 'nonce');

    $brand = sanitize_text_field($_POST['brand']);
    $category = sanitize_text_field($_POST['product_cat']);

    // Query for products based on the brand and category
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_brand',
                'value' => $brand,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        ),
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $category
            )
        )
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    $products = array();
    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();
            $products[] = array(
                'id' => get_the_ID(),
                'name' => get_the_title(),
                'price' => get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_price', true)
            );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }

    wp_send_json_success($products);
}

// Shortcode for filter
add_shortcode('brand_category_filter', 'filter_products_from_brand_and_category_dropdowns');

function filter_products_from_brand_and_category_dropdowns() {
    // Get all product categories excluding "ALL" and second-level categories
    $categories = get_terms(array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ));

    // Get all brands using Perfect Brands WooCommerce plugin
    $brands = get_terms(array(
        'taxonomy' => 'pwb-brand',
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ));

    // Initialize selected values
    $selected_brand = '';
    $selected_category = '';

    // Check if a brand is set in the URL path
    if (is_tax('pwb-brand')) {
        $selected_brand = get_query_var('term');
    }

    // Check if a category is set in the URL path
    if (is_tax('product_cat')) {
        $selected_category = get_query_var('term');
    }

    // Check for query parameters
    if (isset($_GET['pwb-brand']) && !empty($_GET['pwb-brand'])) {
        $selected_brand = sanitize_text_field($_GET['pwb-brand']);
    }
    if (isset($_GET['product_cat']) && !empty($_GET['product_cat'])) {
        $selected_category = sanitize_text_field($_GET['product_cat']);
    }

    ob_start(); // Start output buffering
    ?>
    <h3 class="dropdown-filter">
        Filtrar por Marca | Categoría
    </h3>
    <form role="search" method="get" id="categorysearchform" action="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>">
        <!-- Brand dropdown -->
        <select name="pwb-brand" id="pwb-brand">
            <option value=""><?php esc_html_e('Todas las Marcas', 'woocommerce'); ?></option>
            <?php foreach ($brands as $brand) {
                $selected = ($brand->slug == $selected_brand) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
                printf('<option value="%s" %s>%s</option>', esc_attr($brand->slug), $selected, esc_html($brand->name));
            } ?>
        </select>

        <!-- Second-level category dropdown excluding "ALL" -->
        <select name="product_cat" id="product_cat">
            <option value=""><?php _e('Todas las Categorías', 'woocommerce'); ?></option>
            <?php foreach ($categories as $category) {
                if ($category->name === 'ALL') {
                    continue;
                }
                if ($category->parent != 0) {
                    $parent = get_term($category->parent, 'product_cat');
                    if ($parent->parent == 0) { // Only show second-level categories
                        $selected = ($category->slug == $selected_category) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
                        printf('<option value="%s" %s>%s</option>', esc_attr($category->slug), $selected, esc_html($category->name));
                    }
                }
            } ?>
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" value="product" name="post_type" />
        <button type="submit" id="searchsubmit"><?php _e('Search', 'woocommerce'); ?></button>
    </form>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}

And my jQuery so far:
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

// Function to initialize filters from URL parameters
    function initializeFilters() {
        var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        var brand = urlParams.get('pwb-brand');
        var category = urlParams.get('product_cat');

        if (brand) {
            $('#pwb-brand').val(brand);
        }
        if (category) {
            $('#product_cat').val(category);
        }
    }
    
 // Function to construct the URL with selected filters
    function constructUrl() {
        var brand = $('#pwb-brand').val();
        var category = $('#product_cat').val();
        var baseUrl = 'https://www.erlperfumes.com/productos/';
        var urlParams = [];

        if (brand) {
            urlParams.push('pwb-brand=' + encodeURIComponent(brand));
        }
        if (category) {
            urlParams.push('product_cat=' + encodeURIComponent(category));
        }

        return urlParams.length > 0 ? baseUrl + '?' + urlParams.join('&') : baseUrl;
    }

    // Function to handle redirection
    function handleRedirect() {
        var searchUrl = constructUrl();
        console.log('Redirecting to:', searchUrl); // Log the constructed URL
        window.location.href = searchUrl;
    }

    // Attach event listeners for filter changes
    $('#pwb-brand, #product_cat').on('change', function() {
        handleRedirect();
    });

    // Prevent default form submission
    $('#categorysearchform').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        handleRedirect();
    });

    // Initialize filters on page load
    initializeFilters();

    // Initial call to update field labels
    updateFieldLabels();

    // Update field labels on 'updated_checkout' event
    $(document.body).on('updated_checkout', function() {
        updateFieldLabels();
    });
});


